# Retrieving the last element in csv

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a CSV file as below

```
input.csv
1,2,3
4,5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
```

From this I want to get

```
output.csv
3
8
12
```

I know for a particular fixed size column then I can use

```
cut -d \, -f 1 >output.csv
```

Since this column position varies I could not find it out.Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful trying to just split on `,` if your CSV could contain `,` within a field, as is often the case.  At that point you really need to parse each line, not just tokenize it

Answer (score 6):

A solution is:

```
awk -F "," '{print $NF}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk -F, '{print $NF}'` is best suited in this case as given already

Other ways:

You can reverse the lines, get first column and then reverse again

```
$ rev input.csv | cut -d, -f1 | rev
3
8
12
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*,\(.*\)/\1/' input.csv 
3
8
12
```

Using `grep` and `pcre`

```
$ grep -oP '.*,\K.*' input.csv  
3
8
12
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using something that can actually parse CSV files, in case the last field contains commas itself, like, say

```
13,14,15,"this, here"
```

The last field there is `this, here`, not `here"`

I'd use python, which you could put into a script or you could fake the script at the command line like

```
python <(cat <<EOSCRIPT
import sys
import csv
f = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1]))
for row in f:
  print row[-1]
EOSCRIPT
) input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the CSV data in question is an unusual CSV file (no headers and a varying number of fields per record), I'm instead choosing to work with a more regular CSV file with 5 fields, including headers:

```bash
$ mlr --icsv --omd cat file
```

| 1st | 2nd | 3rd | 4th | 5th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| field with, comma | B | C | D | E |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0x0A |
| A | B | C | D | Hello, world |

```bash
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th
1,2,3,4,5
"field with, comma",B,C,D,E
6,7,8,9,0x0A
A,B,C,D,"Hello, world"
```

We may extract the last column from this by name like so:

```bash
$ mlr --csv cut -f '5th' file
5th
5
E
0x0A
Hello, world
```

... or by field number, like so:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N cut -f 5 file
5th
5
E
0x0A
Hello, world
```

... or by picking out whatever field is the last field:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put -q 'print $[NF]' file
5th
5
E
10
Hello, world
```

Note the `-N` option in the last two commands above.  This instructs `mlr` to read the data as a header-less CSV file.  This allows us to refer to the fields by number instead of by name.

---

You can obviously still work with an irregular CSV file like the one in question. You just have to tell `mlr` that the input is "ragged":

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ragged -N put -q 'print $[NF]' file
3
8
12
```